# Iterate over a "grouped" list

Tags: python, python-3.x

Edited after comment.

I have a list of lists that looks like that:

```
old_list = [['A', 1, 2], ['A', 5, 3], ['A', 3, 2], ['B', 1, 1], ['B', 2, 5], ['C', 3 , 1], ['C', 9, 2]]
```

and I want my function to iterate over it so the output is a list that groups the numerical values of the inner lists by the group identifier (the letter at index 0). See below example of expected output.

```
new_list = [[1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2], [1, 1, 2, 5], [3, 1, 9, 1]]
```

Comment: Is the input correct? Because it is not a list of lists, but its multiple lists with one list item: `[['A', 1, 2]]`. I think that is what makes it complicted.

Comment: Here is what a list of lists would look like (note that not all elements have two brackets around them): `[['A', 1, 2], ['A', 5, 3], ['A', 3, 2], ['B', 1, 1], ['B', 2, 5], ['C', 3, 1], ['C', 9, 2]]`

Comment: edited. Thanks schili.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using a dict, you could achieve a similar result more easily. Just create a dict and check if the group already exists in it.

If it does not, you add the group and add the latter part of the original list slice `item[1:]` (this operator creates a new list with the entries from `item` starting from index 1).

If it does exist, you extend the group with the new values.

```
    old_list = [['A', 1, 2], ['A', 5, 3], ['A', 3, 2], ['B', 1, 1], ['B', 2, 5], ['C', 3 , 1], ['C', 9, 2]]

new_dict = {}
for item in old_list:
    group = item[0]
    if group not in new_dict:
        new_dict[group] = item[1:]
    else:
        new_dict[group].extend(item[1:])
print(new_dict)

# Output:
{'A': [1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2], 'B': [1, 1, 2, 5], 'C': [3, 1, 9, 2]}
```

If you want the list form you asked for in the question, just add the following line at the end.

```
new_list = [item for group, item in new_dict.items()]
print(new_list)

# Output:
[[1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2], [1, 1, 2, 5], [3, 1, 9, 2]]
```