# Group elements of a list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a list of lists that looks like that:

```
old_list = [['A', 1, 2], ['A', 5, 3], ['A', 3, 2], ['B', 1, 1], ['B', 2, 5], ['C', 3 , 1], ['C', 9, 2]]
```

and I want my function to iterate over it so the output is a list that looks like the one below, with one element per grouping item (here the string)

```
new_list = [[1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2], [1, 1, 2, 5], [3, 1, 9, 2]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Iterate over a "grouped" list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67575459/iterate-over-a-grouped-list) (your own question - reposted)

Comment: Yes, but it was closed, so I had to repost it no?

Comment: No. The close banner at the top of the page says *"Add details and clarify the problem being solved. This will help others answer the question. You can [edit the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/67575459/edit)."* After that, it will enter a reopen process and if suitable, it will get reopened

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Via `itertools groupby`:

```
from itertools import groupby

result = [[j for i in k for j in i[1:]]
          for _, k in groupby(old_list, key=lambda x: x[0])]
```

`OUTPUT`:

```
[[1, 2, 5, 3, 3, 2], [1, 1, 2, 5], [3, 1, 9, 2]]
```

`NOTE`: If the list is not sorted then you may need to sort 1st based on 1st element.

```
old_list = sorted(old_list, key= lambda x: x[0])
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a dict to place items of same keys like 'A' and 'B' together.
Then once you are done, you can add dict.values to a bigger list.

```
>>> a = {'a':[1,2,3],'b':[4,5]}

>>> a.values()
dict_values([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5]])
```